# Azure Container Instances change environment variable on start

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

I am creating a container so my developers can run some e2e on their created features.

The container have a environment variable that is pointing to their URL that they want to run the test. This URL is randomly generated every time.

I am looking to change this environment variable of an existing container in Azure Container Instances from CLI.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is Yes and No. The question is very similar to [`Is it possible to add/remove/edit the Environment variables after the container instance has been created?`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/31168)

You can update the variables however it will end up [`recreating the container`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-update) or "Redeploying" it with the update variables which in turns terminates the container and deploys a new one.

Comment: not the response I wanted, but its clear now. Thanks for your help.